# Python- Generate a list of unique combinations from a larger list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 20 products and want to generate the list of all possible combinations of 4 unique products. the order is not important example (a,b,c,d) = (b,d,a,c)... and only one should be listed.

Thank you

Ned

I'm not a programmer and a beginner trying to learn Python.

I calculated 4845 combinations but would like to use python to generate them.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solve using the itertools package, using `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)` where `iterable` is the list of elements that you want to calculate the comb, and `r` is the length subsequences of elements

```py
import itertools

# You define the list of your products
products = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,]

comb = list(itertools.combinations(products, 4))
```

If you want to guarantee that there is not any repetition:

```py
import itertools

# You define the list of your products
products = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,]

# This will remove the duplicate products
products = list(set(products))

comb = list(itertools.combinations(products, 4))
```

Please refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations